# delete_published_posts does not work

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, customization

I made a plugin with a custom post type calls "product".
For some reasons, the administrator cannot move to trash post inside the list table.

I know the capability to do that is `delete_published_posts`.
I checked all capabilities for the administrator on the right page like this :

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
    pretty_var_dump( $user->allcaps );

array (
    'switch_themes' => true,
    'edit_themes' => true,
    'activate_plugins' => true,
    'edit_plugins' => true,
    'edit_users' => true,
    'edit_files' => true,
    'manage_options' => true,
    'moderate_comments' => true,
    'manage_categories' => true,
    'manage_links' => true,
    'upload_files' => true,
    'import' => true,
    'unfiltered_html' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'edit_others_posts' => true,
    'edit_published_posts' => true,
    'publish_posts' => true,
    'edit_pages' => true,
    'read' => true,
    'level_10' => true,
    'level_9' => true,
    'level_8' => true,
    'level_7' => true,
    'level_6' => true,
    'level_5' => true,
    'level_4' => true,
    'level_3' => true,
    'level_2' => true,
    'level_1' => true,
    'level_0' => true,
    'edit_others_pages' => true,
    'edit_published_pages' => true,
    'publish_pages' => true,
    'delete_pages' => true,
    'delete_others_pages' => true,
    'delete_published_pages' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
    'delete_others_posts' => true,
    'delete_published_posts' => true,
    'delete_private_posts' => true,
    'edit_private_posts' => true,
    'read_private_posts' => true,
    'delete_private_pages' => true,
    'edit_private_pages' => true,
    'read_private_pages' => true,
    'delete_users' => true,
    'create_users' => true,
    'unfiltered_upload' => true,
    'edit_dashboard' => true,
    'update_plugins' => true,
    'delete_plugins' => true,
    'install_plugins' => true,
    'update_themes' => true,
    'install_themes' => true,
    'update_core' => true,
    'list_users' => true,
    'remove_users' => true,
    'promote_users' => true,
    'edit_theme_options' => true,
    'delete_themes' => true,
    'export' => true,
    'edit_product' => true,
    'read_product' => true,
    'delete_product' => true,
    'edit_products' => true,
    'edit_others_products' => true,
    'publish_products' => true,
    'read_private_products' => true,
    'create_products' => true,
    'edit_post' => true,
    'delete_private_products' => true,
    'delete_published_products' => true, //<-- ?!
    'delete_others_products' => true,
    'edit_private_products' => true,
    'edit_published_products' => true,
    'administrator' => true,
)
```

So, I don´t know why it does not work. Someone has got an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I need to see was the posts were draft, 
I had to add the capabilty `delete_posts`.